# Confused between cyclic sum and symmetric sums.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, notation, terminology

four variables $a, b, c, d$ are given, what is the symmetric and cyclic sum?

I thought:

> $$\sum_{cyc} ab = ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd$$
>
> And
>
> $$\sum_{sym} ab = 2(ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd)$$

Which one is correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right, by definition you have $\sum_{sym}f(a,b,c,d)=f(a,b,c,d)+f(a,b,d,c)+f(a,c,b,d)+f(a,c,d,b)+...+f(d,c,b,a)$. In your case f(a,b,c,d)=ab.

Comment: But is the cyclic sum correct @Euler88...

Comment: @Amad27: no, it is not. A cyclic sum is a sum over cyclic permutations of the variables, hence (assuming we have four variables) $$\sum_{cyc} ab = ab+bc+cd+da.$$

Comment: And about the original question: the elementary *symmetric* functions are so called because they are given by *symmetric* sums, not cyclic ones.

Comment: I agree with Jack D'Aurizio. If you define the parameters $(a, b, c, d)$, then the cyclic permutation is found by taking $a -> b -> c -> d -> a$, etcetera.

Comment: Alright, got it

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio If you don't mind: is there a way to imbed the variables under consideration in the notation for a cyclic sum? For example, is it common to write $\displaystyle\sum_{cyc (a, b, c, d)} ab = ab+bc+cd+da?$

Comment: @Ovi: in general the number of the involved variables is clear from the context, so we just use $\sum_{cyc}ab$ instead of $\sum_{cyc(a,b,c,d)}ab$, but there is nothing wrong with your notation, of course.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Okay thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I didn't understand what you mean by 'elementary symmetric functions'. Please explain with one example.

Comment: @Vivek: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Answer (score 4):

Cyclic summations proceed systematically replacing the letters a, b, c, d in a cyclic manner as follows: $a->b->c->d->a$ therefore, defined over the ordered arrangement (a, b, c, d),  $\sum_{cyc}{ab}=ab+bc+cd+da$.

Symmetric summation requires summing over all distinct arrangements as follows: $\sum_{symm}{ab}=ab+ac+ad+ba+bc+bd+ca+cb+cd+da+db+dc=2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$.

Defined over an ordered set of n distinct elements, the cyclic summation $\sum{ab}$ has n terms, whereas the symmetric summation has $n(n-1)$ terms (which may simplify into fewer terms).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).